# how to solve the problem "requestTooBigException" when using add in couchbase?

Tags: java, couchbase

I use couchbase to be the cache, when I put one key-value,it throws an RequestTooBigException.do you know how to figure out.please tell me if you know, thanks a bunch.

Sorry, I can't provide the code because this problem appears in my company's framework. It happens when I insert a object List as a value,the size of List is 250.Maybe I should change the way of caching?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Could you please provide the part of your code where you have trouble? Thanks.

Comment: How big are the key and value you're trying to cache? Couchbase documents are limited to 20 MB, and keys are limited to 250 bytes (maybe a few bytes less when using collections in Couchbase 7? I'm not absolutely sure....) See [Size Limitations](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/clusters-and-availability/size-limitations.html)

Comment: Sorry, I can't provide the code because this problem appears in my company's framework. It happens when I insert a object List as a value,the size of List is 250.Maybe I should change the way of caching? Thank you for you guys to help me know more detail about couchbase!